# Can't publish feed to Facebook page by Graph API

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created Facebook app for login on web site and publish feed to facebook page.
Website try to auth user with

`scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location,manage_pages but given  access token with scopes: public_profile, email.`

When authorize with admin of facebook app it will be able to post feed on facebook page, any other user can't. Maybe I missed some facebook app config?

I use `org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProvider.api()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, make sure your app is not in **development mode** (*settings > Status & Review*). When the app is in the dev mode, only the developers/admins and testers can test the app.

Second thing, don't use the deprecated `publish_stream` permission, use `publish_actions` instead.

Comment: App is public. Do I submit "publish_actions" for Approved Items ?

Comment: Yes, if your app is ready; first test that you can see the posts. Then submit `publish_actions` for review to make it available for public.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to submit permissions, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Unsuccessful.. as in? they rejected or what?

Comment: Facebook team didn't approve publish_actions and manage_page permissions. Maybe I wrong fill review submission form.